# Declaring variables in a python tkinter button on click command

Tags: python-3.x, variables, button, tkinter

i am trying to figure out a problem i'm having with declaring a variable upon a button click. For instance i wish to assign to the variable `f` the value `True`. I seem to be having trouble with the syntax or method of using the Button function to declare the variable. Do i initialize the variable beforehand? im not quite sure

here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
b1=Button(root,text="test", command=lambda: f=True)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, assignment is a statement, and thus cannot be done with simple `lambda`s, which can only contain expressions *(function calls, variables, attributes, ... **not** statements, returns<sup>1</sup>, breaks, ...)*. To do what you're wanting to do, you must define a normal function as so:

```
f = False

def onclick():
    global f
    f = True
```

This will access the global namescape's `f`, *(use `nonlocal` if you're within another function)* and use that variable within the function. By assigning to this you will change its value in the outer scope.

**Note** that you must have `f` defined in the outer scope before the function can reassign it.

To use it, set the command to `onclick` as such:

```
b1=Button(root,text="test", command=onclick)
```

*A `lambda` isn't necessary as you're passing the function object*

**Note** that the function definition must occur *before* it is passed as the command argument to the new `Button`

*1: By this I mean returning from an outer function, not returns within the `lambda`, as the entire lambda expression itself is returned.*

Comment: hello! I have a similar issue: could I ask you in private chat? @Annonymous